# What is Destination and Target in Route table (AWS VPC)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vpc

What is Destination and Target in Route table?
I can see Destination and target can be configured to Internet gateway, is there any other use case ?

Answer (score 41):

A short answer:

Destination: the packet's **final** destination

Target: where the packet should go **next**, to get it one step closer to the intended destination.

e.g.

You are planning a business trip from the US to Paris.

- Destination: Paris
- Target: US airport, fly to Paris.

Comment: Best example to void confusion.

Answer (score 31):

Each route has a destination and target field.

- *Destination* field specifies the pattern that a request must match with its destination address ([IP or CIDR range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)).
- *Target* field specifies where such a request should be routed. It could be `local` (i.e. to targets in this VPC) or `your-internet-gateway-ID` in case those requests should be routed to the gateway for external/somewhere-else access. [A list of possible target values is here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Route_Tables.html).

Here's an example assuming a VPC with addresses 10.0.0.0/16

```
| Destination | Target      |
|:------------|------------:|
| 10.0.0.0/16 | local       |
|  0.0.0.0/0  | your-igw-id |
```

This will route any request with into-the-VPC destination to local targets in the VPC. If the pattern `10.0.0.0/16` is not met, the `any-ipv4-address aka 0.0.0.0/0` will be considered and the request will be routed to the internet gateway you specified with ID `your-igw-id`.

The order of the routes is irrelevant since the most specific route will be chosen.

Comment: does it correspond to outgoing traffic only? I mean if an instance in my VPC subnet tries to access an IP different from 10.0.0.0/16 mask than it will be routed to internat gateway?
So if incoming traffic from the internet is coming to Internet Gateway, it will be able to access any instances in my VPC subnets?

Comment: Routes and access privileges are two different things. I would use network-level ACLs to control access to the VPC.

Comment: Thanks Marco, you are right - found similar answer here - https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-certified-solutions-architect-associate/discussion/-KMpVAnXhdK34F7NWYF8/route-table-any-concept-of-direction-of-traffic?answer=-KMv2dfSltfBGwTH30SU

Answer (score 28):

*Destination* => IP address/CIDR range .
*Target* => Where you want to send the traffic for the specified destination (e.g. if the destination is my local subnet, mention target as "local")

The Internet gateway is one of the targets (e.g. routing traffic to the internet). Other options for the target would be

- NAT Gateway
- Virtual Private Gateway
- VPC endpoint
- VPC peering connection etc. depending on your architecture

Route table [document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Route_Tables.html) explains it well.

Comment: I feel like there should be a newline between the first word of "range" and the first word of "Target"

Answer (score 6):

This is easy to comprehend, for any entry in a Route Table there are the following 2 parts:

1. **Destination** - This is an IP Address or a CIDR Range. To plan this out, consider outgoing traffic from any instance inside a VPC. This outgoing traffic will have some destination IP Address, and the route will just handle the request to the target, which is the second part of the entry.
2. **Target** - Target is just the destination the request will be redirected to for getting processed.

Example: Destination: 0.0.0.0 and Target: Internet Gateway - Here all traffic will be passed on to the Internet Gateway

Answer (score 2):

This is how I understand?

```
destination : Final target or Goal
target : Immediate target to achieve final target(via)
```

Ex:

> destination can be Orthopedic Doctor
>
> target can be MBBS, which a College student can take(**via**) to reach his final target
> or destination i.e his/her final goal, Orthopedic specialization.

Answer (score 1):

destination is just destination.

target is next hop, but different from on premises, next hop don't use IP address but identifier